# How to trim and form a boxwood hedge for a beginner?

Tags: pruning, boxwood

I would like to put my small boxwood hedge into a rectangular form. I never did this before - I need newbie advices.

It is useful to construct a frame/framework to guide? What material do I need to use as a guide? I assume freehand with an electric is not an option for me.

Can I use my electric hedge-cutter for it?

What else do I need to take care of?

See also my related question: [When is the right time to trim boxwood?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/5838/when-is-the-right-time-to-trim-boxwood)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Topiary or hedge forms of Buxus are usually trimmed to shape 2 or 3 times a year, starting in mid Spring, when the weather has warmed and growth is strong. If you just want a rectangle, then a shaping device is not necessary, unless you feel diffident about your ability to cut in a straight line. Probably best to do it by hand the first few times, and if your Buxus is one of the smaller varieties, such as B. microphylla, then best done by hand all the time. Some people prefer one handed shears for this, but you can do it with ordinary shears, tidying up any stray or woody shoots with secateurs afterwards. All of the implements you choose to use should be sharp.
You can buy framework structures for topiary shapes, but I'm not sure you can get one that's just a simple rectangle.